# How do i get byte[] from raster image in java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, raster

How do I get `byte[]` from raster image in java? I have tried:

`byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte)bufferedImage.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();`

but this throws a `ClassCastException` runtime exception: *"DataBufferInt cannot be cast to DataBufferByte*".

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The error says it all. You can't do the cast. Also, are you reading the files bytes or trying to get the pixel values. If you are trying to get pixel values, they are not linear in the file like most people think

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, the fix for this exception is really simple first i need to take the int[] return from the int[] i = ( ( DataBufferByte ) bufferedImage.getData().getDataBuffer( ) ).getData(); then i can fill the byte[] from int[] but i m not getting the expected results , all i wanted to do is ...i have a BufferedImage and i wanted to extract its raster data  so that i can send that over network

Comment: Use `DataBuffer::getDataType()` before casting it to some other buffer type. See Javadoc.

Comment: Reading an int reads four bytes not one, so some bit work is needed

Comment: ohh @ColeJohnson thanks for refreshing my bits & byte knowledge, so in this case what else you suggest me to do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a byte array using a ByteArrayOutputStream something like this should work:
(note, untested code)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write( bufferedImage, "jpg", baos ); // if your image is a jpg
baos.flush();
byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
```

*edit*
How about this?
You'd need a FileInputstream of your image to read it and write it to the ByteArrayOutputStream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
try {
    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
        bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); 
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    //
}
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: This encodes the raster image in JPEG and gets the bytes of that encoding. The question doesn't look like that's what was asked for.

Comment: @joachim yes, i dont want to compress image , i want to take the data of raster image in byte[] can any one help ?

Comment: You still haven't answered my question, do you want to read the entire file or the pixel values. Because to read the pixel data, you need to understand the JPEG format.

Comment: @zerd1984 thanks for the effort but i m not using FIS to read the image i m capturing screen shots using Robot class also i have BufferedImage so i wanted to extract the data in byte[] so that if i send that data to remote machine , that machine should make a full image using new ImageIcon(receivedByte[]); i hope now you i am clear

Comment: @ColeJohnson oh i didnt notice you asked me a question , i want to read the entire raster image's data and data consists of pixel value in it.

Comment: That requires knowing the format of the file. Using libraries of System.Drawing.Image should work better

Comment: @zukes Why do you need a byte[]? It looks like your image is a 32bit image, so your pixel data is 32 bit as well. Converting it to byte would give you 4 values per pixel. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Zerd1984 yes, i explained you earlier my requirements that i have to export the image over network that to in fastest way possible..can suggest me something ?

Comment: @ColeJohnson thanks for the help , but how can i get data of a image from System.Drawing.Image class..about the format of my file ..my file  is a raw file not encoded or compressed in any format..i m using Robot class to capture screen

Comment: Well if it's raw data, then you should just read each pixel as an int (32bit)

Comment: I agree. Read the data in int[], send it with ObjectOutputStream (or whatever) over your socket, read it as int array. And since you want to use it in ImageIcon you'll need a gif or jpg format anyways, so you'll need to convert your raw data.

Comment: @ColeJohnson , Zerd thanks for your time and suggestion , but if i read each pixels RGB values gather it in a int[] and send it over a network than how can i make a ImageIcon using int[] at client side because ImageIcon c'tor takes byte[], so can you suggest me any work around to solve this problem ?

Comment: As I showed in my answer, you can get a byte[] using the ImageIO class. You said you didn't want to compress your raw data, but since ImageIcon only can handle jpg or gif files, you'll have to compress your data anyway. So you can either send your raw data over a network and compress it there, (using ImageIO as I showed you) or you can compress the data before you send it (which would increase the transmission speed). This depends on what else you want to do with the raw data.